# CDC-1.0/Foundation-1.0,J2SE-1.3

Tags: java-me, awt, environment, java, cdc

How to setup/configure the environment "CDC-1.0/Foundation-1.0,J2SE-1.3" of an OS (for example windows XP, linux)?

Because I want to run the embedded AWT application which requires this environment.

Answer (score 0):

one possibility is to install an IDE which contains all that. the one which seems the most appropriate to me is [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/). go and see on their site, there are some tutorials on installation, setup and project creation

note that there may be other IDEs to perform the same task, i am just not aware of them.